# 'app' level imports with django 1.4?

Tags: python, django

I have a django app that I developed in the 1.2 days. I'm now trying to port it over to the 1.4 project format.

The old way my project was set up was as follows:

```
django_project/
    settings.py
    manage.py
    urls.py
    app1/
    app2/
    app3/
```

I'm changing it to use the new manage.py and my directories look like this:

```
django_project/
    manage.py
    project
        urls.py
        wsgi.py
        app1/
        app2/
        app3/
```

The problem is that all over my code I import stuff like this:

```
from app1.models import SomeModel
```

which now gives me an import error. Doing this fixes it:

```
from project.app1.models import SomeModel
```

I really don't want to have to go all through my project to change all those imports. Is there something I'm missing? Is there an easier way? Or is this how you're supposed to do it?

Comment: For future reference, this is the sort of thing that refactoring tools in an IDE are supposed to do.

Comment: A note to others who are moving to 1.4: make sure your remove `__init__.py` from your project root (the folder that contains both `<project>` module and all apps), if you had one. I'm not sure if that was something that came with 1.3 or if I put it there on accident, but regardless, it will break your imports when using the new `manage.py` to run tests.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not put your apps into the `project` module. Django's `startapp` puts them in the project root, as it was before. `project` module is a place for project-wide settings, urls and such stuff only. Your apps should stay outside, in project root.

Answer (score 1):

You can keep your current layout, since it will works fine. For new projects I think you can start to put your apps inside the 'project' module. If you check the [1.4 Release Notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.4/#updated-default-project-layout-and-manage-py) you'll see it's the recommended layout. But if you are developing generics apps (that you can use in more than one project) probably the better place is project root.